# How can I multiply a range specified by a variable with its offset in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Right now I am trying to search an excel spreadsheet for a specific colored cell. When excel finds a cell that matches the color I then want excel to take the number from that cell and multiply it by its offset which is the cell directly below it. After it has done that then I can store it in another variable. Once all of the colored cells have been found on the sheet it will then add up all of the products and return the answer into another cell. Here is the code I have now for this:

```
Function ColorFunction(rColor As Range, rRange As Range, Optional SUM As Boolean)
Dim rCell As Range

Dim sResult
Dim lCol As Long
Dim vResult
lCol = rColor.Interior.ColorIndex

If SUM = True Then 'If true then sum the colored Cells
    For Each rCell In rRange
        If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then

            vResult = WorksheetFunction.SUM(rCell, vResult) 'Sums the rCell and adds to vResult 'then stores in vResult

        End If
    Next rCell    'Goes to next cell
    Else

    For Each rCell In rRange
        If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then

            oCell = Range("rCell").Offset(1, 0).Select
            pResult = oCell * rCell
            vResult = WorksheetFunction.SUM(pResult, vResult)

        End If
    Next rCell
    End If
    ColorFunction = vResult
End Function
```

Right now I have my true half of the program working just fine. I just cannot get the false part of the program to work in VBA. Any help would be great!

Comment: Can you give more information for what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not correct:

```
oCell = Range("rCell").Offset(1, 0).Select
```

rCell is not name of range but range itselve. Try:

```
oCell = rCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
```

Also you dont need to select the range but get the range value. So this would be more correct:

```
oCell = rCell.Offset(1, 0).Value
```